# How do I get bash completion to work with aliases?

Tags: git, bash, shell, unix, autocomplete

Case in point:

I'm a on mac with bash v3.2.17, I'm using git installed via macports with the bash_completion variant.

When I type `git checkout m<tab>`. for example, I get it completed to `master`.

However, I've got an alias to `git checkout`, `gco`. When I type `gco m<tab>`, I don't get the branch name autocompleted.

Ideally I'd like autocompletion to just magically work for all my aliases. Is it possible? Failing that, I'd like to manually customize it for each alias. So, how do I go about either?

Comment: complete -o default -o nospace -F doesn't work nowadays

Comment: Questions with more upvotes than the top answer often imply great [feature requests](http://savannah.gnu.org/support/index.php?108476)

Comment: Another answer from superuser as someone pointed out to me that my question there was a dupe of this one. http://superuser.com/questions/436314/how-can-i-get-bash-to-perform-tab-completion-for-my-aliases

Answer (score 198, accepted):

As stated in the comments above,

```
complete -o default -o nospace -F _git_checkout gco
```

will no longer work. However, there's a `__git_complete` function in git-completion.bash which can be used to set up completion for aliases like so:

```
__git_complete gco _git_checkout
```

Comment: If you use global alias "g" for git, you could also add ```__git_complete g __git_main``` to get code completition working on all git commands.

Comment: ^^ For those new to git/shell/bash. The above comment refers to a global shell alias, not a native git alias.

Comment: What if `git` was aliased to `g` and checkout is alised to `co` so I do `g co <tab>` but doesn't autocomplete as well.

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: Finally figured out how to do this properly! 
Step 1) Copy `git-completion.bash` from `<your git install folder>/etc/bash-completion.d/` to `~/.git-completion.bash` 
Step 2) add `source ~/.git-completion.bash` to your `.bash_profile` 
Step 3) Add `__git_complete gco _git_checkout` anywhere after the above line in your .bash_profile.
Step 4) Reboot shell and enjoy your alias auto completion! :)

Comment: @benregn I placed it directly below the `source ~/.git_completion.sh` in my `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: -1 This answer seems to assume that you'll have read and understood some older, incorrect answer (but which one?), and therefore know in what file and where in that file this line of text belongs. Try to only assume knowledge of things established in the question.

Comment: There is a nice [Gist](https://gist.github.com/JuggoPop/10706934) that provides all information needed to set it up

Comment: To check the number of leading underscores for commands other than `__git_main` and `_git_checkout` (such as `_git_merge` and `_git_pull`), search in [the .git-completion.bash script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash). All of the common commands (the ones I alias) have only one leading underscore.

Comment: What if the alias you want completion for has nothing to do with git; what if you don't have git installed on your system/server?

Comment: This is not an actual answer because it doesn't actually tell you what to do so much as just provide some information. Very incomplete.

Comment: For people who are looking for the completion script: `find / -name "git-completion.bash"`.

Comment: @OndrejMachulda +1 _Grazie mille!_  Your solution worked!

Comment: @OndrejMachulda But now I get this error with `parallel_env`: "env_parallel: Error: Your environment is too big."

Answer (score 60):

I ran into this problem as well and came up with this code snippet. This will automatically give you completion for all aliases. Run it after declaring all (or any) alias.

```
# wrap_alias takes three arguments:
# $1: The name of the alias
# $2: The command used in the alias
# $3: The arguments in the alias all in one string
# Generate a wrapper completion function (completer) for an alias
# based on the command and the given arguments, if there is a
# completer for the command, and set the wrapper as the completer for
# the alias.
function wrap_alias() {
  [[ "$#" == 3 ]] || return 1

  local alias_name="$1"
  local aliased_command="$2"
  local alias_arguments="$3"
  local num_alias_arguments=$(echo "$alias_arguments" | wc -w)

  # The completion currently being used for the aliased command.
  local completion=$(complete -p $aliased_command 2> /dev/null)

  # Only a completer based on a function can be wrapped so look for -F
  # in the current completion. This check will also catch commands
  # with no completer for which $completion will be empty.
  echo $completion | grep -q -- -F || return 0

  local namespace=alias_completion::

  # Extract the name of the completion function from a string that
  # looks like: something -F function_name something
  # First strip the beginning of the string up to the function name by
  # removing "* -F " from the front.
  local completion_function=${completion##* -F }
  # Then strip " *" from the end, leaving only the function name.
  completion_function=${completion_function%% *}

  # Try to prevent an infinite loop by not wrapping a function
  # generated by this function. This can happen when the user runs
  # this twice for an alias like ls='ls --color=auto' or alias l='ls'
  # and alias ls='l foo'
  [[ "${completion_function#$namespace}" != $completion_function ]] && return 0

  local wrapper_name="${namespace}${alias_name}"

  eval "
function ${wrapper_name}() {
  let COMP_CWORD+=$num_alias_arguments
  args=( \"${alias_arguments}\" )
  COMP_WORDS=( $aliased_command \${args[@]} \${COMP_WORDS[@]:1} )
  $completion_function
  }
"

  # To create the new completion we use the old one with two
  # replacements:
  # 1) Replace the function with the wrapper.
  local new_completion=${completion/-F * /-F $wrapper_name }
  # 2) Replace the command being completed with the alias.
  new_completion="${new_completion% *} $alias_name"

  eval "$new_completion"
}

# For each defined alias, extract the necessary elements and use them
# to call wrap_alias.
eval "$(alias -p | sed -e 's/alias \([^=][^=]*\)='\''\([^ ][^ ]*\) *\(.*\)'\''/wrap_alias \1 \2 '\''\3'\'' /')"

unset wrap_alias
```

Comment: the line `let COMP_CWORD+=$num_alias_arguments` did not work on Mac OS X for some reason. Replacing it with `((COMP_CWORD+=$num_alias_arguments))` fixed it though

Comment: Wow, that's awesome -- thanks!  `wrap_alias` chokes on double quotes in the alias definition, and I guess it doesn't make much sense for multi-command aliases (`alias 'foo=bar; baz'`), so I'm putting an extra `| grep -v '[";|&]'` after the `alias -p`.  Also, it gets a bit slow for hundreds of alias definitions, but I'm happy to confirm that using `echo` instead of `eval` and piping the output into a cache file (which can then be `eval`'ed in one go) works fine and is super-fast.

Comment: Another hint: `wrap_alias` requires the completions to be set up, so I had to move `source /etc/bash_completion` in front of the `wrap_alias` code.

Comment: I think there needs to be `\"` around `\${COMP_WORDS[@]:1}` to make this work with blank spaces in arguments.  (But I don't really know what I'm doing, so I'm not comfortable editing the answer at the moment.)

Comment: This worked for me on OS X 10.7.2 after changing the line `let COMP_CWORD+=$num_alias_arguments` to `let \"COMP_CWORD+=$num_alias_arguments\"`.

Comment: Did the following to wrap only specified aliases:
function wrap_aliases {
   for cmdname in "$@"; do 
      cmdname="$(alias $cmdname | sed 's/sudo //')";
      eval "$(echo $cmdname | sed -e 's/alias \([^=][^=]*\)='\''\([^ ][^ ]*\) *\(.*\)'\''/wrap_alias \1 \2 '\''\3'\'' /')";
   done
}

Comment: OSX 10.7.2 here, didn't work with either @irh's or MarioFernandez's tips. Any ideas what could be wrong or how I can debug this?

Comment: I had to exclude the following aliases: `[[ "_longopt" = $completion_function ]] && return 0`

Comment: Any way I can make this work with sudo? I added `alias agi='sudo apt-get install'` but agi+emac<TAB> doesn't do anything.

Comment: @obvio171 You would need to have a completion function for sudo.

Comment: @HeskyFisher could you give some more detail, please? Sorry, I'm not too experienced with bash.

Comment: @obvio171 I suggest asking this as a stack overflow question.

Comment: @obvio171: From Graham's reply: Add `| sed 's/sudo //'` before the `sed -e 's/alias'` and it should automatically bring in the completion function for the command *after* `sudo`.

Comment: If anyone is having trouble with some aliases not getting the correct completion, please see my comment [here](http://superuser.com/questions/436314/how-can-i-get-bash-to-perform-tab-completion-for-my-aliases#comment1092143_437508)

Comment: See the updated version of this script at http://superuser.com/a/437508/102281 (for example, I added support for COMP_LINE and COMP_POINT which are required for some git completions).

Comment: I'm sorry, but non-threaded comments are the NOT proper place collaborate on code. At a minimum this should be a gist. But, since gists allow neither **issues** to be created or **pull requests** to be offered, this really should be an actual git repo. (even the link John Mellor shared is full comment coders)

Comment: Yikes, cool script, but it fails when it's a non-trivial alias which contains tokens such as `(($UID))` ;) ... still, very cool. I'm using `grep -v` to get rid of the few offending aliases and added that to the pipe sequence right after `alias -p` ...

Answer (score 20):

> Ideally I'd like autocompletion to just magically work for all my aliases. Is it possible?

Yes, it is possible with the [complete-alias](https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias) project (on Linux). Support for Mac is experimental but users have reported success.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is so much better than figuring out how every utility in the world implements bash completion.

Answer (score 19):

In `git-completion.bash` there is a line:

```
complete -o default -o nospace -F _git git
```

Looking at that line (and the _git function) you can add this line to your `.bash_profile`:

```
complete -o default -o nospace -F _git_checkout gco
```

Comment: some of the _git_* bash functions no longer work using this method

Comment: Yes this used to work great until something changed in git_completion.bash... Now it works with the full command but not with the alias.

Comment: See the end of this page for answers that work in modern git.

Comment: this works well - added this to my .bash_profile, and works fine with and without aliases so far: https://github.com/larrybotha/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_profile#L22-L24

Answer (score 15):

I have aliased g='git', and combined with my git aliases I type things like

```
$ g co <branchname>
```

The simpler fix for my specific use case was to add a single line to git-completion.

Right below this line:

```
__git_complete git _git
```

I added this line to handle my single 'g' alias:

```
__git_complete g _git
```

Comment: (I'm using Cygwin.) I couldn't find the file `git-completion` or that line in `/etc/bash_completion.d/git`, but I added `complete -o default -o nospace -F _git g` after my alias in `.bash_aliases` and it worked!

Comment: Beware, that if you edit a file in `/etc/bash-completion.d/` or newly in `/usr/share/bash-completion/`, you will lose your changes whenever that file gets updated using your package manager.

Answer (score 7):

One more option is to use `~/.bash_completion` file. To create the `gco` alias for `git checkout` just put this in there:

```
_xfunc git __git_complete gco _git_checkout
```

Then in `~/.bashrc` you have to put just the alias itself:

```
alias gco='git checkout'
```

Two lines. That's it.

**Explanation:**

The `~/bash_completion` gets sourced at the end of the main bash_completion script. In gentoo I found the main script in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.

The `_xfunc git` bit takes care of sourcing the `git-completion` file for you so you don't need to put anything else in `~/.bashrc`.

The accepted answer require you to copy `.git-completion.sh` and source it from your `~/.bashrc` file which I find lame.

---

PS: I'm still trying to figure out how not to source the whole `git-completion` script into my bash environment. Please comment or edit if you find a way.

Comment: Why is `_xfunc git` required?

Comment: @TomHale I tried to improve the answer. Rather than doing `source ~/.git-completion.sh` I let `_xfunc` do it for me. It just feels nicer and cleaner to do it solely in `~/.bash_completion`. Without the `_xfunc` (or the sourcing) the `__git_complete` function doesn't exist.

Comment: No need for the `~/.bash_completion` file - the `_xfunc` line works for me in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 5):

You could also try using Git aliases. For example, in my `~/.gitconfig` file, I have a section that looks like this:

```
[alias]
        co = checkout
```

So you could type `git co m<TAB>`, and that should expand to `git co master`, which is the `git checkout` command.

Answer (score 5):

[This forum page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=733397) shows a solution.

Put these lines into your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
# Author.: Ole J
# Date...: 23.03.2008
# License: Whatever

# Wraps a completion function
# make-completion-wrapper <actual completion function> <name of new func.>
#                         <command name> <list supplied arguments>
# eg.
#   alias agi='apt-get install'
#   make-completion-wrapper _apt_get _apt_get_install apt-get install
# defines a function called _apt_get_install (that's $2) that will complete
# the 'agi' alias. (complete -F _apt_get_install agi)
#
function make-completion-wrapper () {
    local function_name="$2"
    local arg_count=$(($#-3))
    local comp_function_name="$1"
    shift 2
    local function="
function $function_name {
    ((COMP_CWORD+=$arg_count))
    COMP_WORDS=( "$@" \${COMP_WORDS[@]:1} )
    "$comp_function_name"
    return 0
}"
    eval "$function"
}

# and now the commands that are specific to this SO question

alias gco='git checkout'

# we create a _git_checkout_mine function that will do the completion for "gco"
# using the completion function "_git"
make-completion-wrapper _git _git_checkout_mine git checkout

# we tell bash to actually use _git_checkout_mine to complete "gco"
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _git_checkout_mine gco
```

This solution is similar to [balshetzer's script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342969/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-to-work-with-aliases/1793178#1793178), but only this one actually works for me. (balshetzer's script had problems with some of my aliases.)

Comment: ;This almost works -- I get a couple of errors, but the completion goes through.  Anything else I can do?  

    `-bash: eval: line 28: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '''`  
    `-bash: eval: line 29: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: @pforhan I can see quoting issues above... the `"` quotes inside the `function` string should be quoted as `\"`. This probably eats one of your `'` quotes somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to find the `complete` command and duplicate the line having the alias name instead.

I have `alias d-m="docker-machine"`. In words, `d-m` shall be the alias for `docker-machine`.

So on Mac (via brew), the completion files are in `` cd `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/ ``.
For my case I edited the file called `docker-machine`.
All the way at the bottom there was:

```
complete -F _docker_machine docker-machine
```

So I just added another line, with my alias:

```
complete -F _docker_machine docker-machine
complete -F _docker_machine d-m
```

Comment: This is the best solution for simple (one to one) aliases, like `docker` aliased to `d`. Although for the example in the question, `git checkout` aliased to `gco` is more complex.

Answer (score 2):

First, look up the original completion command. Example:

```
$ complete | grep git

complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main git
```

Now add these to your startup script (e.g. ~/.bashrc):

```
# copy the original statement, but replace the last command (git) with your alias (g)
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main g

# load dynamically loaded completion functions (may not be required)
_completion_loader git
```

The `_completion_loader` line may not be required. But for some situations, the completion function is only loaded dynamically after you type the command and press `TAB` the first time. So if you haven't used the original command, and try the alias + `TAB`, you may get an error like "bash: completion: function '_docker' not found".

Comment: The `_completion_loader` line is always required if the completion script is located in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/`.
For backwards compatibility scripts that are located in `/etc/bash_completion.d` will still be loaded when `bash_completion` is being loaded.
See: [github bash-completion commit](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/commit/c41a76237bc9dcbfa326eeddd026b66d7646d91d)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of answers to this question and like myself I bet a lot of confused readers. For my case I had also had the requirement to have my dotfiles work on multiple platforms with different versions of Git. I also don't `alias g=git` but instead have `g` defined as a function.

To accomplish this I had to slap together different answers here into one solution. Although this reiterates the answers already I thought someone in my boat might find this compilation useful as I would have when I first came to this question.

This assumes older and newer Git completion, Ubuntu defaults, and `brew install git` on MacOS. In the later case the brew installed completions were not being processed by bash (something I will diagnose later).

```sh
# Alias g to git

g() {
  if [[ $# > 0 ]]; then
    git "$@"
  else
    git status -sb
  fi
}

# Preload git completion in Ubuntu which is normally lazy loaded but we need
# the __git_wrap__git_main function available for our completion.
if [[ -e /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git ]]; then
  source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
elif [[ -e /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]]; then
  source /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
fi

if command_exists __git_complete; then
  __git_complete g _git
elif command_exists __git_wrap__git_main; then
  complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main g
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

[Felipe Contreras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10474/felipec), who is already quite active for Git completion features (see [Zsh completion in Git 2.30](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64758130/6309)) proposes (for -- possibly -- Git 2.31, Q1 2021) a public function which will help with alias autocompletion.

His proposal:

> [Back in 2012 I argued](https://lore.kernel.org/git/1334524814-13581-1-git-send-email-felipe.contreras@gmail.com/T/#u) for the introduction of a helper that would
> allow users to specify aliases like:
>
> ```
> git_complete gf git_fetch
> ```
>
> Back then there was pushback because there was no clear guideline for public functions (`git_complete` vs `_git_complete` vs `_GIT_complete`), and some aliases didn't actually work.
>
> Fast-forward to 2020 and there's still no guideline for public functions, and those aliases still don't work (even though I sent the fixes).
>
> This has not prevented people from using this function that is clearly needed to setup custom aliases (this page), and in fact it's the recommended way.
>
> But it is cumbersome that the user must type:
>
> ```
> __git_complete gf _git_fetch
> ```
>
> Or worse:
>
> ```
> __git_complete gk __gitk_main
> ```
>
> 8 years is more than enough time to stop waiting for the perfect to come; let's define a public function (with the same name) that is actually user-friendly:
>
> ```
> __git_complete gf git_fetch
> __git_complete gk gitk
> ```
>
> While also maintaining backwards compatibility.
>
> The logic is:
>
> 1. If `$2` exists, use it directly
> 2. If not, check if `__$2_main` exists
> 3. If not, check if `_$2` exists
> 4. If not, fail

Answer (score -1):

If you use `alias g='git'`, i add this line of code in `.bash_aliases`

```
complete -o default -o nospace -F _git g
```

Answer (score -1):

You can bind <kbd>Tab</kbd> to `alias-expand-line` and `complete` (its default action) in `~/.inputrc`. To do that you first need to bind each action to a key and then chain them together thus:

```
"\M-z":alias-expand-line
"\M-x":complete
TAB:"\M-z\M-x"
```

You can use whatever key combinations you like, I use the Meta one because it is free. See [`man 3 readline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Interaction.html) for more information.

Now, if you open a new terminal and type the alias:

```
gco m<TAB>
```

The line will be transformed into

```
git checkout master
```

Of course, <kbd>Tab</kbd> will still work as usual even if no alias is involved.

Answer (score -2):

I know this question is about bash but in case you're using zsh this change to [@hesky-fisher answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793178/5923666) will fix it.

From

```sh
# For each defined alias, extract the necessary elements and use them
# to call wrap_alias.
eval "$(alias -p | sed -e 's/alias \([^=][^=]*\)='\''\([^ ][^ ]*\) *\(.*\)'\''/wrap_alias \1 \2 '\''\3'\'' /')"
```

to:

```
# For each defined alias, extract the necessary elements and use them
# to call wrap_alias.
eval "$(alias | sd '^([^=]+)=(.+)' 'wrap_alias $1=$2')"
```

You need to have [`sd`](https://github.com/chmln/sd) (this can be replaced by `sed` but `sd` is much better in my opinion)

This is done because zsh doesn't have `alias -p` and `alias` output in zsh doesn't output

```
alias <something>=<value>
```

like in bash, but rather

```
<something>=<value>
```

---

BTW, I put the init code in the `.zlogin` file