# How to enable git file tab completion with zsh compinit?

Tags: git, file, tabs, zsh, zsh-completion

I have a problem with the zsh tab completion: After running:

```
autoload -U compinit
compinit
```

Git tab completion for files does not work any more. For example if I type git add my_f to complete my_file, nothing happens. The zsh git completion only seems to work for git branches and tags.

Without the compinit stuff, git file completion works, but of course I'm missing out all the fancy branch completion stuff.

So... Is there a way to make git file completion AND git branch completion possible at the same time in zsh? This would really help me a lot.

Comment: In my .zshrc I have 'autoload -U compinit' then 'compinit' on a separate line, and completions work fine for me. Are you running a single command, or is the formatting confusing me?

Comment: Completing files after `git add` also works for me (`zsh` 4.3.10-dev-1). One surprising thing is that it only offers untracked and tracked-but-modified files when completing `git add` (this is OK since those are the only things you would need to add). For `git diff`, it offers all tracked files and all branches.

Comment: @Chris Johnsen: You are right, it does work with files that fit the current git command, like untracked files in the case of git add. I tried the completion without paying attention to that. So thank you very much!

Comment: If you are in a git rebase process and want to resolve a conflict git add does not offer the file you want to use.

Answer (score 10):

(I'm adding an answer here mostly to get it off the unanswered list.)

As you can see from the comments, it does work. I believe the whole zsh situation has recently improved significantly, too:

> commit 06f44c3cc5ca5eca638f300a518c65aa98d26d6d
>
> Date:   Mon Sep 6 08:33:19 2010 -0400
>
> completion: make compatible with zsh
>
> Modify git-completion.bash so that it also works with zsh when using bashcompinit. ...

So, if you happen across this googling, and your completion isn't working, try upgrading your [git-completion.bash](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=contrib/completion/git-completion.bash;hb=HEAD) (link points to the blob from git.git HEAD). Current git version is 1.7.3.2; it should make it into the next one.

Comment: While there has been some recent work to make git.git’s `contrib/git-completion.bash` usable via with `bashcompinit` under *zsh*, a typical *zsh* installation is more likely to use the *git* completion that comes with *zsh*: [Completion/Unix/Command/_git](http://zsh.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=zsh/zsh;a=blob;f=Completion/Unix/Command/_git;hb=HEAD).

Comment: I don't know when it changed, but I just checked and my completion is working very nicely for Git under Zsh.  (I've gotten so used to it failing that I don't think I've tried using it for years.)  I'm on Git 1.8.3.4, for what it's worth

Answer (score 0):

Note that, with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), the instructions for command line completion (in contrib/) for zsh have been updated.

See [commit 3ebd945](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ebd9457353f16c523503d6434636e05686d7f6c) (02 Jul 2020) by [Alexey (`ogonkov`)](https://github.com/ogonkov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bbdbe08](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbdbe08bd73fa9dcd92c613874d06fe719059326), 02 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ebd9457353f16c523503d6434636e05686d7f6c): fix zsh installation instructions
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alexey</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Stefan Haller</sup>

> - Fix wrong script in completion configuration. zsh wants bash completion path here, not path to itself.
> - Add `compinit` autoload command, since whole thing didn't work if it is not loaded.

So the command would be:

```sh
# The recommended way to install this script is to make a copy of it in
# ~/.zsh/ directory as ~/.zsh/git-completion.zsh and then add the following
# to your ~/.zshrc file:
#
#  fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)
#  autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

---

Warning: With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), Zsh autocompletion (in `contrib/`) has been patched, as mentioned [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64671003/6309) by its author "[Felipe Contreras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10474/felipec)".

See [commit af806a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af806a2c2417d21dc024bf013ec511765441e286), [commit 441ecda](https://github.com/git/git/commit/441ecdab37fefdacf32575a60aa523b2367c46f7), [commit 8030684](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8030684beb7af806909c3fa79d3d4017121a753c), [commit 5a364d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a364d2a18311de1791375731678ca13cde89f13), [commit 35a4170](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35a4170d8656b27d08458c3c381dd163199da4f3), [commit bbd7f45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbd7f45884ca379e3cd28bb5fb8e804bcfb3360c), [commit 2769e56](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2769e567d140a51e4e6e426fe776005ae889e9b0), [commit 9d76052](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d760527addc576c87e9b0e66b63376e580b434a), [commit 9a397ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a397ea5ad59e64ff6eebfd1d7dad43aac790e0a), [commit 46af9b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46af9b371929c3c3c9cc0f5b4aa9bcb3089e6405), [commit 5d64fb2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d64fb20511270ffb2d939210a5afe66419f69ab), [commit cf6ce01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf6ce01660ada0286193025f7358c2d52bdb4fae), [commit 35e29fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35e29fbce6bbddf9a74d85ec1541ef806b6f08a8), [commit ecaf798](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecaf798999c1cb730560668710584759151b6624), [commit 2f459b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f459b0060948299be4bfa00c21f574140dcbe63), [commit 94b2901](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94b2901cfe23c077207a563e544fd8dc11a832ce), [commit a7804a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7804a11c16c8562c71b537170a4802a058b7dd6), [commit 3791968](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3791968bfe8485353f95e692c5a3891e4a02c5c4), [commit aa1f1f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa1f1f8010db3ed9a35579f2e83c574650c41237), [commit 162f1a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/162f1a5610fa4de331207c84a8c281088486e5a7), [commit bed6356](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bed635664c4a60f4b19baff02f487aa4c0cd591e), [commit 81f717b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81f717bb268e86eee5701b8199d8f030938a184c), [commit ea625a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea625a39fe5dfcaa3df0d1ee53a40008213acd59), [commit 98fc268](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98fc2684a90bfb9edaae2cb8d5129b4ca7698ddc) (27 Oct 2020), and [commit 44b37ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44b37abb2aabdb49e9f44161b7eafba3f03e4da5), [commit cb9dcbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb9dcbdbe4b3cb5d13f75ac3282b048bcf7bcc45), [commit 2c7cdc5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c7cdc55738257f050e2b83aa94766f50ed60e15), [commit 5eb25bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5eb25bcf0f89a40627b8c23af408af1892705372), [commit 4ce2b51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ce2b5167bb63e7001e43ec5386528fb77c088fa) (24 Oct 2020) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4560eae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4560eae44f43d6cda027550dbc814bb4b1a9f638), 09 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/162f1a5610fa4de331207c84a8c281088486e5a7): bash: remove zsh wrapper
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>

> It has been deprecated for more than eight years now, it's never up to date, and it's a hassle to maintain.
>
> It's time to move on.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), there is a hotfix for a recent breakage.

See [commit 0764964](https://github.com/git/git/commit/076496457e1abe3058d48cb5c387d1face704494) (05 Dec 2020), and [commit c5dd0c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5dd0c861ab0db5ad1ecaf9508bdddca83c5cc6e) (30 Nov 2020) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7d92da3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d92da37871dceb732a56f5a3aecf0be872a40ab), 08 Dec 2020)</sup>
<sup>Cc: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
<sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>
<sup>Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>

> ### [`completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/076496457e1abe3058d48cb5c387d1face704494): bash: fix gitk alias regression

> Long time ago when the `_git_complete` helper was introduced, `_gitk` was replaced with `__gitk_main`, and a placeholder for backwards compatibility pointing to `__git_wrap_main_gitk` was left in place.
>
> When "`__git_complete gitk __gitk_main`" was called, that created the `__git_wrap__gitk_main` helper, which is just basically "`__git_func_wrap __gitk_main`" plus `complete` options.
>
> Unfortunately the [commit b0a4b2d257](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0a4b2d2570974f2050b5d43828dd8146505753e) ("`completion`: add support for backwards compatibility", 2012-05-19, Git v1.7.11-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b19ea23473c45dd6d39b55b3d2134cc812820c41)) missed a previous instance of a call to `_gitk` in `_git_gitk`
>
> So, basically we had `__git_wrap__git_main -> __git_func_wrap __git_main -> __git_complete_command gitk` -> `_git_gitk` -> `_gitk` -> `__git_wrap__gitk_main -> __git_func_wrap __gitk_main -> __gitk_main`.
>
> There was never any need to call `__git_func_wrap` twice.
> Since `_git_gitk` is always called inside the wrapper, it can call `__gitk_main` directly.
>
> And then, in [commit 441ecdab37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/441ecdab37fefdacf32575a60aa523b2367c46f7) ("`completion`: bash: remove old compat wrappers", 2020-10-27, Git v2.30.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4560eae44f43d6cda027550dbc814bb4b1a9f638) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4d83eee9239207622e2b1cc43967da5051c189c)) `_gitk` was removed, which triggers the following error:
>
> ```
> _git_gitk:9: command not found: _gitk
> ```
>
> Let's call the correct function: __gitk_main.

---

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), update to the command line completion (in contrib/) for tcsh.

See [commit ff7b83f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff7b83f5629c0c00910384a0f524d89d3a8bf804) (18 Aug 2021) by [Takashi Iwai (`tiwai`)](https://github.com/tiwai).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4c3bddb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c3bddb64f3cd906dec0335cb6d1b6e8bf54646b), 03 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff7b83f5629c0c00910384a0f524d89d3a8bf804): `tcsh`: Fix regression by drop of wrapper functions.
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Takashi Iwai</sup>

> The cleanup of old compat wrappers in bash completion caused a regression on tcsh completion that still uses them.
> Let's update the tcsh call site as well for addressing it.
>
> Fixes: [441ecda](https://github.com/git/git/commit/441ecdab37fefdacf32575a60aa523b2367c46f7) (`completion`: bash: remove old compat wrappers, 2020-10-27, Git v2.30.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4560eae44f43d6cda027550dbc814bb4b1a9f638) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4d83eee9239207622e2b1cc43967da5051c189c)) ("completion: bash: remove old compat wrappers")