# git completion in zsh: __git_func_wrap:3: : not found

Tags: git, autocomplete, zsh, tig

`git-completion.zsh` and `git-completion.bash` are installed automatically when running `brew install git`:

```
❯ ls -l /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
lrwxr-xr-x 56 quanta  7 Jul 18:54 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git -> ../../../Cellar/git/2.27.0/share/zsh/site-functions/_git

❯ ls -l /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash
lrwxr-xr-x 71 quanta  7 Jul 18:54 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash -> ../../../Cellar/git/2.27.0/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash
```

`/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` is included in `fpath`:

```
❯ echo $fpath
/usr/local/share/zsh-completions
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/share/zsh/5.7.1/functions
```

For some reasons, sometimes when I type `git reba` and press <kbd>tab</kbd>:

```
❯ git reba
__git_func_wrap:3: : not found
__git_func_wrap:3: : not found    

❯ type __git_func_wrap
__git_func_wrap is a shell function from /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash
```

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L3517-L3522

```
❯ grep -A5 '^__git_func_wrap' /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash
__git_func_wrap ()
{
    local cur words cword prev
    _get_comp_words_by_ref -n =: cur words cword prev
    $1
}
```

What the default completion is:

```
❯ complete -p git
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap_tig tig
complete _bash bash
```

Continue inspect:

```
❯ type __git_wrap_tig
__git_wrap_tig is a shell function from /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/tig-completion.bash
```

The thing is I cannot find this function in [tig-completion.bash](https://github.com/jonas/tig/blob/master/contrib/tig-completion.bash)

```
tig: stable 2.5.1 (bottled), HEAD
Text interface for Git repositories
https://jonas.github.io/tig/
/usr/local/Cellar/tig/2.5.1 (15 files, 875.9KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2020-07-06 at 16:01:38
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/tig.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: readline ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
A sample of the default configuration has been installed to:
  /usr/local/opt/tig/share/tig/examples/tigrc
to override the system-wide default configuration, copy the sample to:
  /usr/local/etc/tigrc

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completions and functions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

Looks like there is some changed recently: https://github.com/jonas/tig/commit/26ab51d28133354bfaa94d064bff37d29b3c30e3

but where is `__git_wrap_tig` function?

PS: As I said above, this problem is not happen every time. Sometimes, when I opened a new tab and check the default completion and it is just:

```
❯ complete -p git
complete _bash bash
```

and `git` completion worked as expected.

---

**Reply to @user1934428:**

```
❯ grep '__git_complete ' /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash
__git_complete ()
__git_complete git __git_main
__git_complete gitk __gitk_main
__git_complete git.exe __git_main
```

and one more invocation of `__git_complete` is in [tig-completion.bash](https://github.com/jonas/tig/blob/master/contrib/tig-completion.bash#L98):

```
# we use internal git-completion functions, so wrap _tig for all necessary
# variables (like cword and prev) to be defined
__git_complete tig _tig
```

Comment: The error message occurs in line 3 of the function `__git_func_wrap`, and you found out where the function is defined. Why don't you post the offending line?

Comment: Sorry, it's here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L3517-L3522. I added it into my question. Thanks.

Comment: Don't post a link. The function you are linking to may or may not the same as the version which happens to be on you machine. Copy the relevant part of exactly that function and post it here. Since the error is on line 3, it will likely be sufficient to post the first 4 lines or so.

Comment: They are the same; I checked before posting. The reason I post a link is to help other can look around. Anyway, I updated my question to include that func from the file on my machine.

Comment: Did you also check that rest of the file is identical too? Because the error you got means that $1 in `__git_func_wrap` is empty, which in turn means that $2 in `__git_complete` is empty.  However, I see only 3 invocations of `__git_complete` and all of them look fine.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you for taking time to help me troubleshoot this. I replied by appending to my original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217354/discussion-between-quanta-and-user1934428).

Comment: The same thing is happening to me, and after seeing the mention of tig completion, I found out that it stops working **after** I try to complete a tig command.

Comment: I don't know if it should be like this, but on a new shell, after successfully completing a git command, `complete -p git` returns no output. After trying a tig completion, `complete -p git` has an output (similar to the one above), but it stops working.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you ignore the bash wrapper completion that comes with git and use only the git completion that comes with zsh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR

This is a problem with the `tig` completion definitions, and not with the `git` completion definitions.

Activating completion on `tig` breaks completion for `git`.

- If `tig` is activated after `git`, then `tig` completion works and `git` completion is broken.
- If `tig` completion is activated before `git`, then they are both broken.

### Mitigation:

Install the old versions of the completion scripts.

Unlink _tig and tig-completion.bash in `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` and replace with these older versions.  Rename `tig-completion.zsh` as `_tig` when downloading.

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonas/tig/91912eb97da4f6907015dab41ef9bba315730854/contrib/tig-completion.zsh
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonas/tig/c72aa4dab21077231a97dcca8e3821d7b35fe7db/contrib/tig-completion.bash

```sh
cd /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions && \
rm -f _tig tig-completion.bash && \
wget -O _tig https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonas/tig/91912eb97da4f6907015dab41ef9bba315730854/contrib/tig-completion.zsh && \
wget -O tig-completion.bash https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonas/tig/c72aa4dab21077231a97dcca8e3821d7b35fe7db/contrib/tig-completion.bash
```

### Solution:

TODO: File issue with tig.  This is a regression with the new completion script as implemented in [jonas/tig#960](https://github.com/jonas/tig/pull/960)

### States:

I start with git tab completion working, and then at some point the shell "goes bad."  I actually have three states

1. initial state.  working.  `complete` not defined.

   ```sh
   % which complete
   ```
2. still working after a first tab completion which creates a definition for   `complete`

   ```sh
   % git <TAB>
   add       -- add file contents to the index
   bisect    -- find by binary search the change that introduced a bug
   ...
   % which complete
   complete () {
           return 0
   }
   ```
3. not working.  `complete` function defined referencing bash

   ```sh
       complete () {
           emulate -L zsh
           local args void cmd print remove
           args=("$@")
           zparseopts -D -a void o: A: G: W: C: F: P: S: X: a b c d e f g j k u v p=print r=remove
           if [[ -n $print ]]
           then
                   printf 'complete %2$s %1$s\n' "${(@kv)_comps[(R)_bash*]#* }"
           elif [[ -n $remove ]]
           then
               for cmd
               do
                       unset "_comps[$cmd]"
               done
           else
                   compdef _bash_complete\ ${(j. .)${(q)args[1,-1-$#]}} "$@"
           fi
       }
   ```

### Research

#### complete() function:

unsetting the complete function `unset -f complete` does not magically fix it.  I think this may leave me with no completion for git?

#### virtual envs

I jump in and out of virtual envs, and thought that was related, but a controlled example of jumping in and out and manually setting VIRTUAL_ENV and etc did not bleed over and affect the completion system.

distraction, not related

#### local variables

Digging further I found a lot of local variables set in the third case, "bad shell."

I removed each of these local variables without any positive effect:

```sh
% unset REPLY
% unset __git_repo_path
% unset __tig_commands
% unset __tig_options
% unset _ack_raw_types
% unset $_cmd_variant
% unset _cmd_variant
```

#### tig

Progress!  I can move from state 1 to state 2 by invoking completion on tig:

```sh
% git <TAB>
add       -- add file contents to the index
bisect    -- find by binary search the change that introduced a bug
...
% tig <TAB>
% git <TAB>
__git_func_wrap:3: : not found
```

related broken state by completing with tig first:

```sh
% tig <TAB>
__git_complete:5: command not found: complete
% which complete
complete () {
        emulate -L zsh
        local args void cmd print remove
        args=("$@")
        zparseopts -D -a void o: A: G: W: C: F: P: S: X: a b c d e f g j k u v p=print r=remove
        if [[ -n $print ]]
        then
                printf 'complete %2$s %1$s\n' "${(@kv)_comps[(R)_bash*]#* }"
        elif [[ -n $remove ]]
        then
                for cmd
                do
                        unset "_comps[$cmd]"
                done
        else
                compdef _bash_complete\ ${(j. .)${(q)args[1,-1-$#]}} "$@"
        fi
}
% git <TAB>
__git_func_wrap:3: : not found
```

#### fpath and tig completion

```sh
% echo $fpath
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/5.7.1/functions

% for f in $fpath; do ls $f/*tig*; done | cat
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_tig
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/tig-completion.bash
zsh: no matches found: /usr/share/zsh/site-functions/*tig*
zsh: no matches found: /usr/share/zsh/5.7.1/functions/*tig*
```

#### Brew sources for site-functions for git, tig

- tig completions from tig version 2.5.1
- git completions from git version 2.28.0

```sh
% cd /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
% ls -l *tig*
_tig -> ../../../Cellar/tig/2.5.1/share/zsh/site-functions/_tig
tig-completion.bash -> ../../../Cellar/tig/2.5.1/share/zsh/site-functions/tig-completion.bash
% ls -l *git*
_git -> ../../../Cellar/git/2.28.0/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
git-completion.bash -> ../../../Cellar/git/2.28.0/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash
```

#### Tig completions in `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`

- `_tig`

  ```sh
  #compdef tig
  #
  # zsh completion wrapper for tig
  # ==============================
  #
  # You need to install this script to zsh fpath with tig-completion.bash.
  #
  # The recommended way to install this script is to copy this and tig-completion.bash
  # to '~/.zsh/_tig' and '~/.zsh/tig-completion.bash' and
  # then add following to your ~/.zshrc file:
  #
  #  fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)


  _tig () {
    local e
    e=$(dirname ${funcsourcetrace[1]%:*})/git-completion.bash
    if [ -f $e ]; then
      GIT_SOURCING_ZSH_COMPLETION=y . $e
    fi
    e=$(dirname ${funcsourcetrace[1]%:*})/tig-completion.bash
    if [ -f $e ]; then
      . $e
    fi
  }
  ```
- `tig-completion.bash`

  ```sh
  #compdef git gitk

  # zsh completion wrapper for git
  #
  # Copyright (c) 2012-2013 Felipe Contreras <felipe.contreras@gmail.com>
  #
  # You need git's bash completion script installed somewhere, by default it
  # would be the location bash-completion uses.
  #
  # If your script is somewhere else, you can configure it on your ~/.zshrc:
  #
  #  zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script ~/.git-completion.zsh
  #
  # The recommended way to install this script is to make a copy of it in
  # ~/.zsh/ directory as ~/.zsh/git-completion.zsh and then add the following
  # to your ~/.zshrc file:
  #
  #  fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)

  complete ()
  {
          # do nothing
          return 0
  }

  zstyle -T ':completion:*:*:git:*' tag-order && \
          zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' tag-order 'common-commands'

  zstyle -s ":completion:*:*:git:*" script script
  if [ -z "$script" ]; then
          local -a locations
          local e
          locations=(
                  $(dirname ${funcsourcetrace[1]%:*})/git-completion.bash
                  '/etc/bash_completion.d/git' # fedora, old debian
                  '/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git' # arch, ubuntu, new debian
                  '/usr/share/bash-completion/git' # gentoo
                  )
          for e in $locations; do
                  test -f $e && script="$e" && break
          done
  fi
  GIT_SOURCING_ZSH_COMPLETION=y . "$script"

  __gitcomp ()
  {
          emulate -L zsh

          local cur_="${3-$cur}"

          case "$cur_" in
          --*=)
                  ;;
          *)
                  local c IFS=$' \t\n'
                  local -a array
                  for c in ${=1}; do
                          c="$c${4-}"
                          case $c in
                          --*=*|*.) ;;
                          *) c="$c " ;;
                          esac
                          array+=("$c")
                  done
                  compset -P '*[=:]'
                  compadd -Q -S '' -p "${2-}" -a -- array && _ret=0
                  ;;
          esac
  }

  __gitcomp_direct ()
  {
          emulate -L zsh

          local IFS=$'\n'
          compset -P '*[=:]'
          compadd -Q -- ${=1} && _ret=0
  }

  __gitcomp_nl ()
  {
          emulate -L zsh

          local IFS=$'\n'
          compset -P '*[=:]'
          compadd -Q -S "${4- }" -p "${2-}" -- ${=1} && _ret=0
  }

  __gitcomp_nl_append ()
  {
          emulate -L zsh

          local IFS=$'\n'
          compadd -Q -S "${4- }" -p "${2-}" -- ${=1} && _ret=0
  }

  __gitcomp_file_direct ()
  {
          emulate -L zsh

          local IFS=$'\n'
          compset -P '*[=:]'
          compadd -f -- ${=1} && _ret=0
  }

  __gitcomp_file ()
  {
          emulate -L zsh

          local IFS=$'\n'
          compset -P '*[=:]'
          compadd -p "${2-}" -f -- ${=1} && _ret=0
  }

  __git_zsh_bash_func ()
  {
          emulate -L ksh

          local command=$1

          local completion_func="_git_${command//-/_}"
          declare -f $completion_func >/dev/null && $completion_func && return

          local expansion=$(__git_aliased_command "$command")
          if [ -n "$expansion" ]; then
                  words[1]=$expansion
                  completion_func="_git_${expansion//-/_}"
                  declare -f $completion_func >/dev/null && $completion_func
          fi
  }

  __git_zsh_cmd_common ()
  {
          local -a list
          list=(
          add:'add file contents to the index'
          bisect:'find by binary search the change that introduced a bug'
          branch:'list, create, or delete branches'
          checkout:'checkout a branch or paths to the working tree'
          clone:'clone a repository into a new directory'
          commit:'record changes to the repository'
          diff:'show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc'
          fetch:'download objects and refs from another repository'
          grep:'print lines matching a pattern'
          init:'create an empty Git repository or reinitialize an existing one'
          log:'show commit logs'
          merge:'join two or more development histories together'
          mv:'move or rename a file, a directory, or a symlink'
          pull:'fetch from and merge with another repository or a local branch'
          push:'update remote refs along with associated objects'
          rebase:'forward-port local commits to the updated upstream head'
          reset:'reset current HEAD to the specified state'
          restore:'restore working tree files'
          rm:'remove files from the working tree and from the index'
          show:'show various types of objects'
          status:'show the working tree status'
          switch:'switch branches'
          tag:'create, list, delete or verify a tag object signed with GPG')
          _describe -t common-commands 'common commands' list && _ret=0
  }

  __git_zsh_cmd_alias ()
  {
          local -a list
          list=(${${${(0)"$(git config -z --get-regexp '^alias\.')"}#alias.}%$'\n'*})
          _describe -t alias-commands 'aliases' list $* && _ret=0
  }

  __git_zsh_cmd_all ()
  {
          local -a list
          emulate ksh -c __git_compute_all_commands
          list=( ${=__git_all_commands} )
          _describe -t all-commands 'all commands' list && _ret=0
  }

  __git_zsh_main ()
  {
          local curcontext="$curcontext" state state_descr line
          typeset -A opt_args
          local -a orig_words

          orig_words=( ${words[@]} )

          _arguments -C \
                  '(-p --paginate --no-pager)'{-p,--paginate}'[pipe all output into ''less'']' \
                  '(-p --paginate)--no-pager[do not pipe git output into a pager]' \
                  '--git-dir=-[set the path to the repository]: :_directories' \
                  '--bare[treat the repository as a bare repository]' \
                  '(- :)--version[prints the git suite version]' \
                  '--exec-path=-[path to where your core git programs are installed]:: :_directories' \
                  '--html-path[print the path where git''s HTML documentation is installed]' \
                  '--info-path[print the path where the Info files are installed]' \
                  '--man-path[print the manpath (see `man(1)`) for the man pages]' \
                  '--work-tree=-[set the path to the working tree]: :_directories' \
                  '--namespace=-[set the git namespace]' \
                  '--no-replace-objects[do not use replacement refs to replace git objects]' \
                  '(- :)--help[prints the synopsis and a list of the most commonly used commands]: :->arg' \
                  '(-): :->command' \
                  '(-)*:: :->arg' && return

          case $state in
          (command)
                  _alternative \
                           'alias-commands:alias:__git_zsh_cmd_alias' \
                           'common-commands:common:__git_zsh_cmd_common' \
                           'all-commands:all:__git_zsh_cmd_all' && _ret=0
                  ;;
          (arg)
                  local command="${words[1]}" __git_dir

                  if (( $+opt_args[--bare] )); then
                          __git_dir='.'
                  else
                          __git_dir=${opt_args[--git-dir]}
                  fi

                  (( $+opt_args[--help] )) && command='help'

                  words=( ${orig_words[@]} )

                  __git_zsh_bash_func $command
                  ;;
          esac
  }

  _git ()
  {
          local _ret=1
          local cur cword prev

          cur=${words[CURRENT]}
          prev=${words[CURRENT-1]}
          let cword=CURRENT-1

          if (( $+functions[__${service}_zsh_main] )); then
                  __${service}_zsh_main
          else
                  emulate ksh -c __${service}_main
          fi

          let _ret && _default && _ret=0
          return _ret
  }

  _git
  ```

Comment: This is an oustanding answer. @spazm Do you have any objection to me posting a link to your answer in an issue on the `tig` Github repo? I don't see one yet, but perhaps you are waiting to work on this further here.

Comment: You are probably on to something regarding `complete()`. I'm the one in the copyright of that last tig script, but the `complete()` hack has been fixed in my project: `git-complete`, but no in Git upstream. I've sent them multiple patches, but they haven't fixed it.

[Relevant commit](https://github.com/felipec/git-completion/commit/8241b7373e147a58e6cb26535a65b56307819dc1).

Comment: Your `tig-completion.bash` file is wrong. That file corresponds to `git-completion.zsh`.

Answer (score 2):

The `__git_complete` function contains this:

```
__git_complete ()
{
    local wrapper="__git_wrap${2}"
    eval "$wrapper () { __git_func_wrap $2 ; }"
}
```

The new code of tig calls it like this:

```
__git_complete tig _tig
```

This code is effectively creating a wrapper called `__git_wrap_tig`.

```
__git_wrap_tig { __git_func_wrap _tig }
```

However, these functions are not meant to be used by the Zsh completion.

The Zsh completion (latest version [here](https://github.com/felipec/git-completion/blob/master/git-completion.zsh)) is meant to be sourcing the bash completion by itself, and then calling `__tig_main` directly, bypassing any wrappers.

The problem is that the main tig function **must** be called `__tig_main`, not `_tig`. I've sent [a patch](https://github.com/felipec/tig/commit/51e499c22ef07ef960c724287208094deaad7a0b) to fix this and other discrepancies with the official git completion.

If you install all the latest relevant files:

1. [git-completion.bash](https://github.com/felipec/git-completion/blob/master/git-completion.bash)
2. [git-completion.zsh](https://github.com/felipec/git-completion/blob/master/git-completion.zsh) (as _git)
3. [tig-completion.bash](https://github.com/felipec/tig/blob/fc/fixes/contrib/tig-completion.bash)
4. [tig-completion.zsh](https://github.com/felipec/tig/blob/fc/fixes/contrib/tig-completion.zsh) (as _tig)

Into your `fpath` (e.g. `~/.zsh/`), it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment, you wrote, that you have installed the completion system from https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash , but for zsh, the correct sources should be the ones at https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh

According to the installation instruction: git-completion.zsh must be sourced from .zshrc. The bash version must be accessible from it.

Comment: Ah, `git-completion.bash` is installed automatically when running `brew install git`.

Comment: But you do have put the git-completion.zsh into your .zshrc, don't you?

Comment: `git-completion.zsh` was installed at `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git`.

Comment: And you are sourcing it from your .zshrc?

Comment: Yes, `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` is included in `fpath`.

Comment: In this case, it looks like you have done the setup correctly. Of course it would be helpful if you could reproduce the case, but in this case, it might be a bug, and perhaps you could contact the [maintainer](https://github.com/felipec) by email.