# Git autocomplete in bash aliases?

Tags: git, bash

I'm using `go` as a simple bash alias for `git checkout branchname`. The thing that I miss is the autocomplete feature that works with the full `git checkout branchna...` command, but not in the alias.

Is there a way to instruct Bash to "inherit" the autocomplete "driver" for another command?

Comment: Duplicate with : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4219/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-for-command-aliases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get bash completion to work with aliases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342969/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-to-work-with-aliases)

Comment: Related: if the alias sets a custom `git-dir` then use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216748/).

Comment: @Claudio, would you consider revisiting your choice of Accepted Answer? The most-upvoted answer seemed a lot more useful to me (who came looking with exactly the same problem you had)

Comment: @Brondahl hey, thanks for the suggestion. I just did it.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

After using `complete -F`:

```
complete -F _git_checkout go
```

Tabbing after `go` may result in:

```
bash: [: 1: unary operator expected
```

#### Instead of `complete`, use `__git_complete`

This is git bash completion's built-in function for this purpose.

After declaring your alias, bind the correct auto-complete function to it:

```
# Main git completions (prior to git 2.30, you an use _git instead of __git_main)
alias g="git"
__git_complete g __git_main

alias go="git checkout"
__git_complete go _git_checkout

alias gp="git push"
__git_complete gp _git_push
```

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I was having the same issue. It was because I had the `__git_complete` function in my bash-completion package (installed via homebrew with `brew install bash-completion`), which was not currently sourced in my bash profile. Had to add this line to ~/.bash_profile: `[ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion ] && . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion`

Comment: Adding __git_complete under `git checkout` alias worked like charm !!!

Comment: It should be `__git_main`, not `_git`.  The reason `_git` exists is for backwards compatibility only, it's basically `__git_main` wrapped.

Comment: And `_git` not longer works as of Git 2.30

Comment: if you want branch name completeion as well, take a look here https://levelup.gitconnected.com/upgrade-your-command-line-for-software-development-with-git-autocomplete-1fb946c14750

Comment: Just as an aside to this answer, it can be easier to set up aliases using git's built-in alias support (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases). Then there is no need for additional git completion setup (beyond if you have an alias for git itself)

Answer (score 47):

If you can find out the completion function used by the original command, you can assign it to the alias using `complete -F`.

For example, on my ubuntu box, the completion function used by `git checkout` is `_git_checkout` (found in `/etc/bash_complete.d/git`).

#### Example

Before running `complete -F`:

```
[me@home]$ git checkout <TAB><TAB>
HEAD            master          origin/HEAD     origin/master

[me@home]$ alias go="git checkout"

[me@home]$$ go <TAB><TAB>
.git/                precommit_config.py  README.md            SvnSentinel/         
.gitignore           precommit.py         startcommit.py       tests/
```

After:

```
[me@home]$$ complete -F _git_checkout go

[me@home]$$ go <TAB><TAB>
HEAD            master          origin/HEAD     origin/master
```

Comment: on ubuntu 12.04 the completions seem to live in: /etc/bash_completion.d/git and not /etc/bash_complete.d/git

Comment: If `complete -F` doesn't work for you, see the answer about `__git_complete` below http://stackoverflow.com/a/24665529/3779

Answer (score 32):

On Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) the following works. Add something like this snippet (with your aliases) to your preferred bash configuration file e.g. `.bashrc`, `.bash_aliases` `.bash_profile`.

```
# define aliases
alias gc='git checkout'
alias gp='git pull'

# setup autocompletion
if [ -f "/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git" ]; then
  source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
  __git_complete gc _git_checkout
  __git_complete gp _git_pull
else
  echo "Error loading git completions"
fi
```

In general the format of the `__git_complete` directive is the following:

```
__git_complete <YOUR ALIAS> _git_<GIT COMMAND NAME>
```

This combines wisdom from the existing answers in a single up-to-date answer, thank you all.

Comment: I would just like to add that for an ssh/terminal only session, put everything in .bashrc. I had the git complete stuff in .bash_profile and the aliases in .bashrc and couldn't get it working. It wasn't until I added an `echo "profile"` / `echo "rc"` that I figured that one out.

Comment: still works on August 2021 in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Why isn't this the number one answer? It is a complete example showing where __git_complete comes from...

Answer (score 20):

In Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, the file I needed to source was `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git`. So in `.bash_custom` (or .bashrc, whatever):

```
[ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git ] && . /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
__git_complete g __git_main
```

Comment: The reason of requiring manual loading is that currently Bash loads those files dynamically. So far it loads them according to their name. The file won't be loaded until you hit a Git completion, which is too late by the time `.bashrc` was read.

Answer (score 5):

As somebody else answered you should use `__git_complete`, otherwise the script will fail.

```
alias g="git"
__git_complete g __git_main

alias g="gl"
__git_complete gl _git_log
```

But you shouldn't use `_git` for the main command, it's `__git_main`.

Unfortunately a lot of information about the completion is hidden, but you can find more on the README of my fork: [git-completion](https://github.com/felipec/git-completion).

Comment: I was using `_git`, which was removed in Git 2.30, breaking my completion. This works; thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To add to other excellent answers: normally you have a lot of Git aliases and it may be tedious to manually forward completions for all of them. Here's a small trick to do this automatically:

```
if [ -f "/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git" ]; then
  # Enable Git completions for aliases
  . /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
  for a in $(alias | sed -n 's/^alias \(g[^=]*\)=.git .*/\1/p'); do
    c=$(alias $a | sed 's/^[^=]*=.git \([a-z0-9\-]\+\).*/\1/' | tr '-' '_')
    if set | grep -q "^_git_$c *()"; then
      eval "__git_complete $a _git_$c"
    fi
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux Mint, the accepted answer didn't work for me. I was getting `bash: [: 1: unary operator expected` .

I found the following linked response worked quite well - with the troubleshooting section the user provided to be quite helpful.  https://superuser.com/questions/436314/how-can-i-get-bash-to-perform-tab-completion-for-my-aliases

Answer (score 2):

I realize you're specifically asking about bash aliases, but for those coming here looking for autocomplete *in bash* for complex git aliases, see [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash).

In particular:

```
# If you use complex aliases of form '!f() { ... }; f', you can use the null
# command ':' as the first command in the function body to declare the desired
# completion style.  For example '!f() { : git commit ; ... }; f' will
# tell the completion to use commit completion.  This also works with aliases
# of form "!sh -c '...'".  For example, "!sh -c ': git commit ; ... '".
```

Answer (score 0):

For `macOS`, run the following to install bash completion

```
 brew install bash-completion
```

Then add the following

```
[[ -r "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]] && . "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
```

to your .bashrc or .bash_profile