# How to change the language of my git?

Tags: linux, git, command-line, terminal

My ˋgitˋ is in german, it says:

ˋAuf Zweig masterˋ

instead of

`On branch master`

with `git status`.

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Probably you locale is german. You can see it by `locale`. Try to change it by: `export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: I also needed `export LANGUAGE=en_US:en`

Comment: @dafnahaktana See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55139754/974555).

Answer (score 25):

The reason for this is that your command line language is set to German.
So when you do:

```
echo $LANG
```

you will see:

```
de_DE.UTF-8
```

To change this, do:

```
echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc
```

assuming your standard shell is bash.

Don't forget:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes changing the `LANG` environment variable alone is not good enough.

You may also need to add `LC_ALL`

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

According to The [IEEE and The Open Group - Environment Variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

It is because the environment variables starting by `LC_*` will be **used first** by your system before `LANG`:

> **The values of locale categories shall be determined by a precedence
>   order**; the first condition met below determines the value:
>
> 1. If the LC_ALL environment variable is defined and is not null, the
>      value of LC_ALL shall be used.
> 2. If the LC_* environment variable (LC_COLLATE, LC_CTYPE, LC_MESSAGES,
>      LC_MONETARY, LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME) is defined and is not null, the
>      value of the environment variable shall be used to initialize the
>      category that corresponds to the environment variable.
> 3. If the LANG environment variable is defined and is not null, the
>      value of the LANG environment variable shall be used.
> 4. If the LANG environment variable is not set or is set to the empty
>      string, the implementation-defined default locale shall be used.

To change it permanently, you need to paste the code above into your favourite shell configuration file (probably `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`)

Then to apply the modification do:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

Otherwise, just open a new terminal.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, setting `LANG` or `LC_ALL` was not enough.  I also had a `LANGUAGE` environment variable which was set to `en_GB:en_US:de`.  Despite the ordering, which is presumably an order of preference, it resulted in a German language response from `git` and other commandline-programmes.  When I changed it to `en_GB:en_US`, `git` and other programmes became English.

Comment: yes adding  <alias git='LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_Us git'> to bashrc did the trick. Thanls

Comment: How do you access bashrc to do this?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOrtiz Do you mean how to edit it?  I think Tom means they added `alias git="LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_US git"` to their `.bashrc` (no `<` or `>` signs!)

Answer (score 1):

As explain in @Tom comment, it is possible to add alias. In my case, I add in my Ubuntu *~/.bash_aliases*

```bash
alias giten='LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_Us git'
# setup autocompletion
if [ -f "/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git" ]; then
  source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
  __git_complete giten _git_main
else
  echo "Error loading git completions"
fi
```

so if I use *git*, it is in my language, if I use *giten*, it is in english

**NOTA**: the auto-completion is lost if you don't add if … completion

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the answer by bcag2: I like this answer, because it changes language for git, and it leaves the system setting intact. 
Actually I cannot imagine you all don't have the "g" alias for git, and the completions will still work if you do it like this:

```
alias g="LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_Us git"

# setup autocompletion 
if [ -f "/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git" ]; then
   source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
   __git_complete g _git_main
else
   echo "Error loading git completions"
fi
```

Comment: In my case under ubuntu 22.04, your setting returns me `__git_complete : command not found`. I replace by ```# setup autocompletion
if [ -f "/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git" ]; then
  source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
  __git_complete g _git_main
else
  echo "Error loading git completions"
fi``` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869227/git-autocomplete-in-bash-aliases)

Comment: Right, I assumed the autocompletions already configured. I added your safe autocompletion setup to the answer. Thanks!