# Git cli in Russian after brew upgrade

Tags: git, command-line-interface

My git cli switched to russian after brew upgrade. I've tried to find why, or how, but no clue.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.19.0
```

How do I fix this!?

My locale doesn't mention russian at all

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but on the bright side, if you ever land a software job in Moscow, you'll be ahead of the game :-)

Comment: What does `echo $LANG` print? Does running `export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` (or some other English locale) fix your issue?

Comment: Related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540815/how-to-change-the-language-of-my-git

Comment: @jujobs $LANG was empty, but setting it helped. Strange that it somehow changed with upgrading to a new version...

Answer (score 12):

It happened because of removing "NO_GETTEXT=1" line here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/2049390786eff5dd50862ee63ddca822dc138c64.

I think setting LC_* is not an option that's why I recommend either remove /usr/local/Cellar/git/{version}/share/locale/es directory or rebuild git from sources.

If you want to *rebuild git from sources* you need to edit homebrew git formula:

```
$ brew uninstall git
$ brew edit git

<<<
- depends_on "gettext"
+ depends_on "gettext" => :optional
<<<
- args = %W[
+ ENV["NO_GETTEXT"] = "1" if build.without? "gettext"
+
+ args = %W[
<<<
:wq

$ brew install -s git
```

then your git will be built with NO_GETTEXT=1 flag that disables translations.

Hope it will help.

I have commented corresponding thread with that issue: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31980#issuecomment-425894125. Voting may help to fix it.

Comment: Great, thanks. Because secondary translations were moving me crazy. Living with a temp solution of `export LANG="en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: In my case I had to modify `depends_on "gettext" :optional` by `depends_on "gettext" => :optional`

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround is to add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file:

```
alias git="LANG=\"en_US.UTF-8\" git"
```

Then execute `source ~/.bashrc` (or `source ~/.zshrc`) and voila :)

Comment: love the solution

Answer (score 0):

I added to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias git="LANG=\"en_US.UTF-8\" git"
```

Then execute `source ~/.bash_profile` and git is in English at Terminal.