# Git in Spanish after upgrade

Tags: git, macos, command-line, homebrew

After upgrading to git 2.19 the messages are in Spanish.

I don't have `LANG` set, but after setting it to English:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Then it works again, but before upgrade, it wasn't necessary to set up explicitly the language (what did it change the default recognition?)

**UDPATE1:**

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/32008

https://public-inbox.org/git/CAKd-JgS3omKbN+OzQL2dUun6Seg9CjDNk8KEj9m83xdTZE=7FA@mail.gmail.com/T/

This issue has been seen in other command-line as wget.

All point to be gettext() ?

**UPDATE2:**

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31980
still researching gettext.

Comment: Seems like similar to this question we had three hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426922/git-cli-in-russian-after-brew-upgrade

Comment: right, the same question :)

Answer (score 7):

There is a bug report in progress, as seen in [this similar case](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=153737156815678&w=2)

> After update to Git 2.19 Git's output suddenly appeared in Russian.
>   I can use `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to switch it to English back, but it's very weird.
>
> this appears to be a bug in how `brew` changed its builds of Git, and also affects packages besides git.
>
> This problem is not specific to Git.
>   Ævar asked if the problem also occurs with other command-line programs, and indeed it does.
>   For instance, I tried with 'wget' installed via `brew`, and it exhibits the same odd behavior.
>   Ævar suggested that there might be some magic special-casing English, which makes me wonder if brew builds such magic into `gettext`(?) or if the magic is part of
>   MacOS itself.

**[Alexey Storozhev (`storoj`)](https://github.com/storoj)** comments in  [`Homebrew/homebrew-core` issue 31980](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31980#issuecomment-425894125)

> I totally agree with @moonfruit that removing `--with-gettext` option was a mistake.
>   But another mistake happened and [gettext support became mandatory](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/32008). It affects badly if your system has one or more languages.
>   For example, I have `en_RU` locale and my `git` output became Russian.
>   That's not an option for me and I can't help with it in a normal way;
>
> - I don't want to use `LC_LANG=en_US` in my `bash_profile` because it will affect everything in my system,
> - I don't want to make an alias like `git="LC_LANG=en_US git"` either.
>
> Another point to return `--with-gettext` back is the way `git` supports i18n.
>   [According to `INSTALL`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fe8321ec057f9231c26c29b364721568e58040f7/INSTALL#L164-L166), the only way to use English is exactly `NO_GETTEXT` flag enabled. Otherwise, [`po/${lang}.po` files](https://github.com/git/git/tree/fe8321ec057f9231c26c29b364721568e58040f7/po) will be used to determine available languages.
>   As you see, that directory does not contain "`en.po`" file. And if you are running `git` with `gettext` support and `en_RU` locale, `gettext` will look for following files: `share/locale/{en_RU,en,ru_RU,ru}/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo`. It finally finds "`ru`" one and uses Russian language for output which is totally unusable. I don't have any piece of development software localized in Russian.

So... [rebuilding Git with `NO_GETTEXT=1` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52592260/6309) (disabling translations) seems to be the only workaround for now (Q4 2018).