# alias g='git' and have bash completion still work

Tags: git, bash, autocomplete, git-completion

For an alias to `git` itself, eg. `alias g=git`, you'll find your answer more easily here.

For `git` subcommand aliases, eg. `alias gco = "git checkout"`, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342969/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-to-work-with-aliases).

---

I type `git` far too often, so I've aliased it:

```
alias g='git'
```

However, now I can't do:

`g com`<kbd>tab</kbd>

and have the completion present me with:

`g commit`

How do I get completion running again?

---

**Duplicate differentiation**

This [equal-first meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213979/336223) suggests keeping the specific case with a with a link to the more generic question. I've added the link to the more generic case in this edit.

The asserted duplicate question is more generic - but mostly about aliases to `git` subcommands, rather than an alias to git itself.

This question is about the specific case where the alias is to `git` itself.

In the marked duplicate, the `git`-itself case is only answered in the 4th shown answer, and in a comment to the first listed answer. Reading another comment is required for the second piece of the puzzle (source `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git`) to get it working via that method.

Addressing the links in the comments below:

- @ewcz's link is the marked duplicate and has already been addressed
- Remy J's links

  1. This is question as asked (and answered) is also about `git` subcommands
  2. This is an even more generic question about non-`git` aliases, which doesn't isn't near to the best solution in this case
  3. This is the same as @ewcz's link (already addressed)

Comment: I'm running `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342969/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-to-work-with-aliases ?

Comment: Maybe these few links will help you out 1. [Git autocomplete in bash aliases?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9869478/6683985) 2. [How do I get bash completion for command aliases?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4220/184872) 3. [How do I get bash completion to work with aliases?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009611/6683985) 4. ...

Answer (score 10):

At the end of your `.bashrc`, add:

```
_xfunc git __git_complete g _git
```

If you see `bash: _xfunc: command not found`, use the longer form:

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
__git_complete g _git
```

**Reload bash**

`exec bash`

(This answer was inspired by the [kub1x's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35659508/5353461) and the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009611/5353461) in a question about [completion of git subcommand aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342969/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-to-work-with-aliases))

Comment: Neither of those worked for me on macOS using git 2.37.x installed via `brew install git`. I'm using brew installed bash as well (5.1), and in my `~/.bashrc`, after my `alias g=git` I added: `complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main g`). Restarted with `exec bash -l` and it now works with `g br<Tab>` and even my git aliases like `g ch <Tab>` (checkout). Use `complete | grep git` to find out what you need to call in your ~/.bashrc and change 'git' at the end to 'g'.

Comment: does not work as it should: g st <tab-press> does produce something git related, but mingled, completions for stage/status/stash are not shown and it cannot be completed. ie. does not actually work

Comment: this is the way: alias g='git';
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git;
__git_complete g __git_main

Answer (score 3):

Add the following in your .bashrc file:

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
complete -o default -o nospace -F _git g
```

Comment: does not work. g st <tab-press> produces: g stabash: completion: function `_git' not found

Comment: this is the way: alias g='git'; source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git; __git_complete g __git_main