# Git completions for alias functions

Tags: macos, git, shell, zsh

I have a few aliased functions such as `gb` for `git branch` and `gco` for `git checkout` in my .zshrc. This works great when I remember the full branch name I'm creating, deleting, checking out, etc. However, I noticed that completions no longer seem to work. Previously, I could do

```
$ git checkout m<TAB>
```

and it would autocomplete master if that was the name of a branch. Now, however, I get the following error when I use:

```
$ gco m<TAB>
_git:15: parse error: condition expected: 1
```

I'm not sure why this is occurring. It appears there's possibly a missing argument, but I'm not sure why.

*Edit:*

I'm setting an alias for `git branch` and `git checkout` in my .zshrc file like this:

```
alias gco='git checkout'
alias gb='git branch'
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342969/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-to-work-with-aliases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little more digging around I found a solution to the same problem for bash that looks to work just as well for zsh. After defining the two functions `__define_git_completion` and `__git_shortcut` you would call `__git_shortcut` to set up your alias and the completion in one call.

```
__define_git_completion () {
eval "
    _git_$2_shortcut () {
        COMP_LINE=\"git $2\${COMP_LINE#$1}\"
        let COMP_POINT+=$((4+${#2}-${#1}))
        COMP_WORDS=(git $2 \"\${COMP_WORDS[@]:1}\")
        let COMP_CWORD+=1

        local cur words cword prev
        _get_comp_words_by_ref -n =: cur words cword prev
        _git_$2
    }
"
}

__git_shortcut () {
    type _git_$2_shortcut &>/dev/null || __define_git_completion $1 $2
    alias $1="git $2 $3"
    complete -o default -o nospace -F _git_$2_shortcut $1
}

__git_shortcut  ga    add
__git_shortcut  gb    branch            # I use this one.
__git_shortcut  gba   branch -a
__git_shortcut  gco   checkout          # and I use this one, too.
__git_shortcut  gci   commit -v
__git_shortcut  gcia  commit '-a -v'
__git_shortcut  gd    diff
__git_shortcut  gdc   diff --cached
__git_shortcut  gds   diff --stat
__git_shortcut  gf    fetch
__git_shortcut  gl    log
__git_shortcut  glp   log -p
__git_shortcut  gls   log --stat
```

- [View Gist from the original answer here.](https://github.com/bronson/dotfiles/blob/731bfd951be68f395247982ba1fb745fbed2455c/.bashrc#L81%3aL114)
- [Found the answer on this thread.](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Bash-tab-completion-for-git-fetch-alias-is-broken-on-Git-1-7-7-1-td6980366.html)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should create the aliases in the .gitconfig if you want autocomplete to work as well. However you will have to spell the git command out.

```
[alias]
gb = branch
gco = checkout
```

etc...

You can also add aliases like this:

```
git config –-global alias.gb branch
```

They will be appended to your .gitconfig

cheers

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this adds an alias to the `git` command so the alias `gb` here would add `git gb m<TAB>` completions, but I'm trying to use just `gb m<TAB>`

Comment: `git gco foo` isn't any shorter/more-useful than e.g. `git checkout foo`. it's not defining `gco foo`.