# bash alias not autocompleting same as aliased

Tags: bash, autocomplete, alias

I'm trying to replace vlc with the more intuitive watch command.

**desired functionality**

> 1. *Autocompletion*
>
>    watch /path/to/mo <kbd>Tab</kbd>  --> watch /path/to/movie.avi
> 2. *Execute vlc*
>
>    watch /path/to/movie.avi <kbd>Enter</kbd> # this should run `vlc /path/to/movie.avi

Currently I'm using an alias todo above :

**~/.bashrc**

```
...
alias watch='vlc'
...
```

This meets `execute vlc` above, but doesn't give the correct `autocompletion` [ 1 ]

**current behaviour**

> $ vlc /path/to/mo <kbd>Tab</kbd> --> vlc /path/to/movie.avi ( successfully completing )
>
> $ watch /path/to/mo <kbd>Tab</kbd> --> watch /path/to/mo ( not autocompleting.. )

As @GUIDO mentions, `watch` is an inbuilt command.
This is somehow affecting the autocomplete. Changing to `play` works, but would like to understand why this doesnt work, and how to fix..

**note**

similar to [How do I get bash completion to work with aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342969/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-to-work-with-aliases)

but defining the function wrap_alias ( in my ~/.bashrc ) and calling

```
wrap_alias watch vlc ''
```

doesn't fix the autocomplete issue

Comment: are you aware that `watch` is a command present already in most if not all linux distributions by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get bash completion to work with aliases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342969/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-to-work-with-aliases)

Comment: @pasabaporaqui the wrap_alias in that answer does not solve the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we look at the completion for command 'vlc' we see:

```
$ complete | grep vlc
complete -F _minimal vlc
```

so the wrapper function is "_minimal". We can use the same for the new command:

```
$ alias watch='vlc'
$ complete -F _minimal watch
```

and subject must be now solved.