# How do I get bash completion to work with aliases in Windows 10 bash?

Tags: git

I have an aliases.sh file modified with

```
alias gc='git checkout'
```

and upon checking out a long branch name, if I type
`gc <branchstring>` + TAB , auto-complete doesn't work, in order for the full branch name to appear.

Answer (score 5):

I looked through everything in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342969/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-to-work-with-aliases) to try to make it work for & tailor what **kpsfoo** said, but for the Windows 10 OS.

The steps would be to:

1) Copy the ***git-completion.bash*** file from

```
<your git install folder>/etc/git-completion.bash
```

to

`C:\Users\<YourUserName>\git-completion.bash`

2) add this line of code:

`source ~/git-completion.bash` to your ***aliases.sh*** file

(which can be found in `<your git install folder>\etc\profile.d` )

3) Add `alias gc='git checkout'`
      &
Add `__git_complete gco _git_checkout` anywhere after the  `source ~/git-completion.bash` line in your ***aliases.sh*** file.

4) Reboot your git bash and enjoy your alias auto completion!

Example: 
If I have a branch `VeryVeryLongBranchName` and I'm currently on `dev` branch, and want to switch to it, instead of typing
`git checkout VeryVeryLongBranchName` I can type only 
`gc Very` +*TAB key* and  it is the equivalent of the instruction above.

## An example of everything that I have in my aliases.sh file (and it will be expanded, as I find the need for other aliases) would be:

```
alias ga="git add"
alias gb='git branch'
alias gba="git branch -a"
alias gc='git checkout'
alias gcb='git checkout -b'
alias gcam='git commit -a -m'
alias gm='git merge --no-ff'
alias gps='git push wpdev dev'
alias gpsm='git push wpdev master'
alias gpl='git pull wpdev dev'
alias gplm='git pull wpdev master'
alias st='git status'
alias l='git log --graph --pretty='\''%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\'' --abbrev-commit'
alias last='log -1 HEAD'
alias gs='git stash'

# Enable the __git_complete function to autocomplete aliases once you press TAB
source ~/git-completion.bash

__git_complete ga _git_add
__git_complete gc _git_checkout
__git_complete gm _git_merge
__git_complete gb _git_branch
__git_complete gba _git_branch
__git_complete l _git_log

case "$TERM" in
xterm*)
    # The following programs are known to require a Win32 Console
    # for interactive usage, therefore let's launch them through winpty
    # when run inside `mintty`.
    for name in node ipython php php5 psql python2.7
    do
        case "$(type -p "$name".exe 2>/dev/null)" in
        ''|/usr/bin/*) continue;;
        esac
        alias $name="winpty $name.exe"
    done
    ;;
esac
```

-worth of note: `alias gm='git merge --no-ff'` goes just fine with  `__git_complete gm _git_merge`  (when typing **gm** plus a string from your branch name and pressing **TAB**, it will autocomplete, and, after you run the command, the merge will take into consideration the **--no-ff** rule)

Comment: Good answer, note that `zsh` works without any manual tweaking.

Comment: On my Git version 2.28.0.windows.1, git-completion.bash is located at `<git-installation-folder>/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-completion.bash`